# running 'docker-compose exec ...' within GitLab CI

Tags: docker, docker-compose, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to run a command on container like this `docker-compose exec xyz` from .gitlab-ci.yml file.
The error, which I don't understand, reads `the input device is not a TTY` and then it exits out.

How can I troubleshoot this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TTY is effectively STDIN, you're executing a command (I'm guessing with the `-it`) flag that expects some input after the exec command from STDIN (Like typing a password, or executing bash commands in a running container). As it's a build pipeline it errors because you haven't provided anything. Otherwise can you please provide some more info about your input?

Comment: Actually, I wasn't using the `-it` flag but I did use `-T` flag as a workaround.

Comment: Yeah I had the same issue trying to run `pytest` in my ".gitlab-ci.yml" CI/CD script. `docker-compose exec service_name pytest` wouldn't work, but `docker-compose exec -t service_name pytest` worked!